# How to load Razor partial view in jQuery without using MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I am working on a Umbraco 7 project started without MVC implemented. I try to implement a loading without page refresh. I am stuck now because I need some Razor code to get Umbraco information but I need jQuery to refresh without page refresh.

Here my code:

```
$(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
              cache: false
            });
            $('#filterButton').click(function(){
                $('#content').html(@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/Preferences.cshtml"));
            })
        });
```

I tried with `.load()`with `.html` using `@Html.Action`,`@Html.Partial` etc, but nothing works. I know it is really simple to link a controller to an action like this but it will take me to much time now to change everything.

Can you say me if it is possible or not?

Comment: Try `$('#content').html('@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/Preferences.cshtml")');`

Comment: @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/Preferen‌​ces.cshtml") is use as html content. it doesn't work

Comment: But did you try with the quotes that I suggested? What the javascript console saying?

Answer (score -1):

Please jquery try

```
 $('#content').load("/Partials/Preferences");
```

another html helpers  try 
`@{
Html.RenderAction("Preferences","Partials");
}`

Syntext For

@Html.RenderAction(Action, Controller, Route)

Comment: I asked without mvc